# Nginx- File upload via HTTP request

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http-request, http-post

I want to send an image file to my Nginx server(ubuntu machine).

I add the following code to nginx.conf:

```
location /upload {
  auth_basic                 "Restricted Upload";
  auth_basic_user_file       basic.htpasswd;
  limit_except POST          { deny all; }

  client_body_temp_path      /tmp/;
  client_body_in_file_only   on;
  client_body_buffer_size    128K;
  client_max_body_size       1000M;

  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file; 
  proxy_set_body             off;
  proxy_redirect             off;
  proxy_pass                 http://backend/file;
}
```

After adding that additional code, restart serivce failed.

Where do i anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This link maybe helpful for you: http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

Comment: I think you should see where your image is being uploaded which is usually a server method that receives your image as a POST request, try to check using Developer Tools of web browser and see the response after failed.

Comment: Check the access.log of nginx. I think you're getting a :: [emerg] 38429#0: host not found in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourwebsite -- error